# Insert text into an XML node located by an XPath expression with Java code

Tags: java, xml, xpath, expression, structure

I have an xml document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<request>
<location>
  <address />
</location>
</request> 
</body>
```

My goal is to insert the value "My Address" into this document in order to have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<request>
<location>
  <address>
    My Address
  </address>
</location>
</request> 
</body>
```

I have to reach this goal in a java class that must create this document reading it from an XML file (ok) and i have an XPath expression (/request/location/address) that indicates me where to put my text ("My address"). How to implement a Java class that allows me, starting from xml and XPath string, to insert a text into a node? This java class must be universal, not bound to a particular XML structure (this is the reason why I use an XPath expression instead of getting the XMl structure into the class). I hope my question is clear.

Comment: The XPath `/request/location/address` would not select anything at all in the document as your root element is `body` and not `request`. As for the Java code and XPath, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.InputSource,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29 on how to select a node.

Comment: Yes, i made mistake in writing XPath, thanks. I don't know how to use the correct XPath expression in order to insert the text in that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to do this [vtd-xml](http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf)....

```
import com.ximpleware.*;

public class insertTextNode {
    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException, Exception {
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier();
        if (vg.parseFile("input.xml", true)) {
            VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
            ap.bind(vn);
            xm.bind(vn);
            ap.selectXPath("/body/request/location/address");
            int i=0;
            while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
                xm.insertAfterHead("myAddress");
            }
            xm.output("output.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also solved this problem by myself with JDOM2, but this is a very helpful method, too. When i'll time to write my way i'll update this post with my personal answer. Thank you anyway, vtd.xml-author.

Comment: JDOM Is among the slowest and most resource wasteful api out there, here is the proof http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf